# Use material-ui tooltip on <i> component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tooltip, material-ui

I want to use the [material-ui react tooltip](https://material-ui.com/api/tooltip/) on the following component:

```
const Icon = ({
    name,
    color,
    size,
}) => {

    return (
        <i
            aria-hidden='true'
            style={{
                    fontSize: size,
                    color,
                }}>
            {name}
        </i>
    )
};

export default Icon;
```

The Icon is created through an [Iconfont](https://material.io/tools/icons/).
Implementing the tooltip like this does not work - no tooltip is showing

```
...
icons.map(icon => {
    <Tooltip
        title='Foo'
        placement='right'>
        <Icon
            size={icon.size}
            color={icon.color}
            name={icon.name} />
    </Tooltip>
}
...
```

But, replacing the `<Icon />` through a simple `<i>`, works.

```
...
icons.map(icon => {
    <Tooltip
        title='Foo'
        placement='right'>
            <i>
                {'Bar'}
            </i>
    </Tooltip>
}
...
```

How can I use the `material-ui react tooltip` with th `<Icon />` component?

Comment: try wrapping the icon with a div <tooltip><div><icon/>. someone suggested it in other post

Comment: @NiritLevi thats it!